# Error in console when click on Android Sdk manager

Tags: android, eclipse

when i click on Android Sdk Manager then this error shown in console and don't open Android sdk manager , Please help 
this error line shown 3 times on per click

```
 [2014-01-20 17:59:18 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] /usr/bin/java: 1: /usr/bin/java: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")
```

[image]

```
 .bashrc :- 



 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
    export JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21
    export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
    export ECLIPSE_HOME="/home/rohit/eclipse"
```

Comment: have u set JDK path???

Comment: @AnilBhatiya yes i have set

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem executing Eclipse and I've solved.I was trying to run a jre version which was not registered in the eclipse jre environment.

I checked my java version (linux: java -version), and i saw that it is different with my jre environment version. Then, i went to Eclipse - window- preferences - java- installed jres and i add the build path to java version. In my case, there was a jre version installed in usr/lib/jvm that i had ignored it.

Later, in execution environment i click on javaSE-1.7 and click on compatible jres: java-your-version [perfect match]. OK to changes and my problem was resolved.

I wish this may help you.